# I am a beginner programmer and want to design a Battleship program in LC3 assembly

Tags: lc3

I don't really know how or where to start my algorithm on showing the display grid for the game.

Answer (score 1):

Design the game in pseudocode first, so that you can get the general ideas worked out (data structures, algorithms, etc). Once you have a theoretical design worked out then you can start coding.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good place to start:

http://twoguysonebit.com/2010/02/16/code-battleship-game-written-in-mips-assembly/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would to just dump the display out as strings of text:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 x . B B B B * x x .
1 . . . . . x . . . .
```

etc.

And let the map scroll.

Later, if you want to get fancy, you can (likely) output [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) escape codes for an ANSI terminal, then you can just update the screen as you like...old school.